# how to apply conv2d on masked elements in ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, mask, convolution

for example, I have a matrix

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

And a mask

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

here I have 3 elements that I want to apply conv2d on.

The operation is I want to replace the element in the mask with the int average value of itself and its neighbour.

The kernel is just a simple 3x3

```
1/9 1/9 1/9
1/9 1/9 1/9
1/9 1/9 1/9
```

The result I want is like

```
1 2 3 4
5 3 7 5
1 2 6 4
5 6 7 8
```

The simplest way I know is just to apply conv2d on full ndarray and then set the value with the mask. But I don't want to do the calculation for a large array cause masked elements may be very few.

Currently my solution is use np.argwhere to find all indices, then do the calculation one by one, I was wondering if there is any more elegant solution.

Comment: Are you sure the 2D convolution would be more expensive than selecting the 1s only? Can you provide some code to set up a reproducible random example of a large input?

Comment: in my real case, I have an 1000x1000 pic, and I can filter out some pixel in it, I want to remove these pixels meanwhile fill the hole remained with the average color of its neighbours

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result by implementing a workaround. Here is the suggested workflow for your task:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Apply Conv2D layer to the input
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input)

# Multiply x1 with the mask
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Multiply([x1, mask])

# Compute the complement of the mask and multiply it with the input
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Multiply([input, tf.math.logical_not(mask)])

# Add x1 and x2
out = tf.tf.keras.layers.Add([x1, x2])
```

Additionally, if you prefer, you can encapsulate this functionality within a custom TensorFlow layer. I hope this solution addresses your problem effectively.